# Max Speed Achieved since last code clearning?

Tags: vehicle-speed-sensor

I installed a OBDII bluetooth device in my teenage daughter's car.  What I want to capture is Peak/Max Speed achieved since last code clearing.

The standard PID that comes with the software I'm using only provides current speed, not any historical speed data (ie. Max, Min, ect.).

Can anyone help?

Thx!
Keith

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What software/device are you using? What's the year/make/model/engine of the car?

Answer (score 1):

OBD II is a diagnostic system which allows you to monitor, in realtime, what is going on within the cars' CANBUS data system.  A data logger will allow you to capture driving telemetry which sounds more like what you want.  Either that or a "black box" insurance device which usually includes a user portal.

Comment: I understand that some cars store the max RPM, at least my Toyota according to my understanding does that. Not sure if it can be accessed with standard OBD bluetooth device, or if it requires Toyota-specific readers. If the max RPM is stored, you could perhaps attempt to deduce the speed by guessing the gear, and also, if the max RPM is stored why wouldn't the manufacturer also store the max speed?

Comment: @juhist usually cost - cheap & cheerful...